# grep -c command expansion

Tags: bash, grep

On centos 7 I have this weird behavior:

If I do:

```
grep -v "^#" /etc/security/limits.conf
```

I have:

```
*   soft    nofile  10000
*   hard    nofile  10000
```

if I do:

```
var=$(grep -v "^#" /etc/security/limits.conf)
echo $var
```

I have the results is the grep result plus the files in my working directory.
for example, if I am in /usr I have:

```
bin etc games include lib lib64 libexec local sbin share src tmp soft nofile 10000 bin etc games include lib lib64 libexec local sbin share src tmp hard nofile 10000
```

This only happens with -v option. What I'm missing?

Comment: I made a typo on the title, the command is grep -v not grep -c

Comment: The leading `*` of each line is being expanded when you `echo` it